# Building on Windows fails during linking

Tags: windows, haskell, cabal

I'm trying to build a small hobby project on Windows using the Haskell Platform. I've successfully run (from inside a Cygwin terminal)

```
$ cabal sandbox init
$ cabal install --only-dependencies
```

But, trying to actually build the program results in a whole bunch of the following errors:

```
$ cabal build
...
C:\cygwin\home\Rasmus\haskell-subme\.cabal-sandbox\i386-windows-ghc-7.8.3\HTTP-4000.2.19/libHSHTTP-4000.2.19.a(TCP.o):fake:(.text+0x196f): undefined reference to `shutdownWinSock'
```

(Full log here: https://gist.github.com/Prillan/8a22594fc21635e4f855)

**I'm a complete beginner when it comes to building Haskell programs using cabal, what am I doing wrong? What's up with the combination of Windows and Linux path separators?**

Comment: The problem lies with the `network` package. On windows, I believe to install a newer version of `network` you need to link it with the ld which comes with the Haskell platform. If you have cygwin installed, you most certainly are using the ld which comes with cygwin. The simplest solution is to use the version of network which came with the Haskell platform. I use windows and I have never successfully been able to install a newer version of network when using the Haskell platform. The path separators are not related to this issue.

Comment: I have a bit of a dependency problem, I *have* to (re)install `HTTP` and `network` because `taggy` requires a newer version of `attoparsec`. Would it help if I reinstalled, by compiling ghc, Haskell from "inside" cygwin?

Comment: This might help with installing `network` on Windows: http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2010/12/installing-haskell-network-library-on.html

Comment: Or even the [Minimal GHC Installer](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2014/12/beta-testing-windows-minimal-ghc.html)

Comment: @Cactus The MinGHC worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: @Hashmush since your question was answered, you should post the solution as an answer for the record...